# Dependence and correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics, independence, correlation

Does dependence of two random variables inform us about their correlation coefficient? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much actually. 
Also note that $\rho = 0$ doesn't imply that RVs are independent.

Comment: But how do you know that if they're dependent then $1\le \rho \le 1$?

Comment: $-1\le \rho \le 1$, always holds true.

Comment: That's true, I meant how do we know that $\rho$ isn't a specific value from that interval? We know for example that if $X,Y$ are independent then $\rho = 0$. So can we prove somehow the fact that we don't know much about $\rho$ when they're dependent?

Comment: A fairly simple counter-example to your proposition of that $\rho$ takes a particular value if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent is to take $Y=X$ and then $Y=-X$ and observing that $\rho(X,X) = 1$ and $\rho(X,-X) = -1$